# Distribute iPad app outside of Appstore

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I've developed an app for a company that doesn't want it to go on the appstore.
I just built it on each of their iPads and gave them back, but a year after I had to rebuild all of them, due to some licence restriction (I imagine)

How do I go about putting it on their iPads without having to reinstall every year :)?

Answer (score 1):

[You need the enterprise deployment guide](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

Comment: oh dear, that's expensive :( when it's just 2 iPads with an app that never has to be updated, can't I do it differently?